# In Visual Studio Code, I get "The PowerShell session has terminated due to an error..."

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. In VSC, I can open a file fine. It's when I try to open another folder that I have a problem. When I do that, the VSC screen goes blank, then I get:

> "The PowerShell session has terminated due to an error, would you like
>   to restart it? [Yes, No, Close]"

...and then after a second or so it chooses one of those options for me (it doesn't let me enter anything) and now I'm looking at the new folder's contents.

I have 2 separate PCs, one Win7, the other Win10.  Occurs the same on both.  Version 1.15.1. I can open multiple files from the same folder fine, but not from separate folders without getting the PowerShell session termination message.

Comment: That is just the way it works because VS Code is closing the process/threads the extension creates. I've seen that from the beginning.

Comment: Paul, that explains the PS session termination message if I was trying to close the other files.  But I don't understand why it won't let me open files from different folders at the same time.  I'm not attempting to close anything.
Am I opening the second file wrong?